# Resize input field by value length after ajax query

Tags: java, html, ajax

Javascript

```
// Ajax refresh price value.
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url:"query.php?currency=<?=$currencycode;?>"
    }).done(function(data) {
        $("#value").attr("value", data);
    });
},3000);
```

HTML

```
<input id="value" type="text" value="..." size="1" readonly>
```

query.php file output

```
1234
```

How can I make the input field size to change to query.php file output result length, in my case 1234, the size of input tag should be 4. Also a transition animation to see the change for every refresh, in my case every 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
// Ajax refresh price value.
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url:"query.php?currency=<?=$currencycode;?>"
    }).done(function(data) {
        $("#value").attr("value", data).attr("size", data.length);
    });
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Yep that work, I added this extra line of code: .attr("size", data.length);

Comment: Great! You also talk about a transition animation, could you be a little more specific on what it is you want to achieve with it or mark the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, an example:

```
<input id="counter" type="text" value="1234" size="7" readonly>
<script>
let init="1234";
let i = 5;
setInterval(function() {
     document.getElementById("counter").value=init;
     document.getElementById("counter").size=init.length + 4;
     init += i;
     i++;
},1000);
</script>
```